# i want to hold in bracket to some string value which comes through the xml file

Tags: c#

i am parsing the data through xml file and storing it into the my database i have one field which comes sometimes with slash or sometimes not wih slash,so i want to when the address data is come with slash then i want to hold in bracket for example addrees is come as delhi/d153 the i want to store as a [delhi/d153] can anybody help me with c# code.my code is this

```
address = line.Split('/')[14]+line;
List<string> addressList = new List<string>();
addressList.Add(address);
addressList.Insert(0, "[");
addressList.Add(address+"]");
```

Comment: String interpolation?  String.Format()?  String concatenation?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of the list here?  Wouldnt you just want a string?

Comment: can u send me code after the  first line how we will add the brackets  at runtime .

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you have the data from the XML already coming in as `line`, and that you have your data saved as some kind of array of strings by this point (`yourAddresses`). There wasn't enough code in your question to indicate if you had actually already gotten the data from your XML file or not.

```
string[] yourAddresses = new string[2];
yourAddresses[0] = "delhi/d153";
yourAddresses[1] = "Taj Mahal";

List<string> addressList = new List<string>();
foreach (string line in yourAddresses)
{
    if (line.Contains("/"))
    {
        addressList.Add("[" + line + "]");
    }
    else
    {
        addressList.Add(line);
    }
}
```